# custom star rating with half fill programmatically swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm trying to create a half-filled star rating view.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
func setUpStarStack() {
        for i in 0..<5 {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            if(i==0){
                imageView.tag = 5009
            }
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_nofill")
            stackViewStar.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
            arrayImage.append(imageView)
        }
    self.addSubview(stackViewStar)
    stackViewStar.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Added five empty star images to StackView.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchLocation = touches.first
    let location = touchLocation?.location(in: stackViewStar)
    if(touchLocation?.view?.tag == 5007){
        var intRating:Float = 0
        arrayImage.forEach { (imageView) in
            if ((location?.x)! > imageView.frame.origin.x) {
                let i = arrayImage.firstIndex(of: imageView)
                intRating = Float(i!) + 1
                intRate = Float(intRating)
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_fill")
            } else {
                if(imageView.tag != 5009){
                    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_nofill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fill in half a star depending on the touch location.

Comment: not sure what the question is really, but I reckon you have an image named "img_star_half" or sth like so. If this is purely a matter of "where do I switch between a full star and a demi-one" you could simply say that if the touch is between `imageView.frame.origin.x ` and `imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width / 2`, the star should be filled halfway.

Comment: imageView.frame.origin.x < (location?.x)! && (location?.x)! <= imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width / 2 { imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_half")
                } 

I added this code, but still can't see half star

Comment: Is the last part the answer? Do not include the answer in the question. The answer should be an Answer.

Comment: okay delete and create new answer. Thanks for a advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayImage.forEach { (imageView) in
           if imageView.frame.origin.x < (location?.x)! && (location?.x)! <= imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width / 2 {
                    
                    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_half")
            } else if ((location?.x)! > imageView.frame.origin.x) {
          
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_fill")
            } else {
                if(imageView.tag != 5009){
                    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img_star_nofill")
                }
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).